# stacking pandas value as new row based on string splitting

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Using the following table as an example where ix is the index column:

| ix | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | "hello ::tosplit:: world" | 1 |
| 1 | "hello ::tosplit city" | 2 |

with the following command:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].str.split('::tosplit::', expand=True).stack().reset_index(drop=True).rename('A')
```

the result is:

| ix | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | "hello" | 1 |
| 1 | "world" | 3 |
| 2 | "hello" | 4 |
| 3 | "city" | 6 |

notice how the numbers in column B become random?
I want to preserve the original number of the resulting new stacked row, i.e. :

| ix | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | "hello" | 1 |
| 1 | "world" | 1 |
| 2 | "hello" | 2 |
| 3 | "city" | 2 |

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The second row in your sample data isn't going to split based on on that delimiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to explode the column after splitting instead of expanding on split.

```
df['A'] = df.A.str.split('::tosplit::')
df = df.explode('A')
```

Comment: You're an actual hero. Thank you! I know about explode but i've only used it in Spark SQL :)